# violacion del core usando hilos en C

Tags: c, hilos

este es el proceso que se carga en varios hilos

```
 void *recorreNumero (FILE *entrada, char nomT[], int numT){
 int t = 0, numero = 0 ,primo = -1;
 char linea[13];
 FILE *salida;
 rewind(entrada);
 fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),entrada);
 salida = fopen (nomT,"w"); 
 while (fscanf(entrada, "%i", &numero) != EOF){
    t++;
    printf("%i\n",numero );
}
 int lineasT = t/numT;
 int cont=1;
 rewind(entrada);
 fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),entrada);    
 while (fscanf(entrada, "%i", &numero) != EOF){
    printf("Extraido: %i \n", numero);  
    primo = numprimo(numero);
    fprintf(salida, "%i  %i\n",numero,primo);
    printf("%i\n",primo);
    cont++;
    if (cont == lineasT)
        break;
  }
 printf("Numero de filas: %d %i %s \n",t,primo,nomT);
 fclose(salida);
}
```

ahora el problema se presenta al intentar ejecutar 2 o mas hilos con el mismo procedimiento de la siguiente forma

```
pthread_create (&t1,NULL, recorreNumero(entrada,"t1.txt",1),NULL);
pthread_create (&t2,NULL, recorreNumero(entrada,"t2.txt",2),NULL);
```

el primer hilo, se ejecuta normalmente y arroja los resultados en el fichero que se indica, el problema viene en el segundo hilo, este se ejecuta también al igual que el primero pero, al finalizar salta un msj que dice lo siguiente:

> violacion del segmento ('core'generado)

llevo ya bastante rato dándole vueltas pero no logro llegar a una solución, trate de implementar un `thread_exit(NULL)` al final de `recorreNumero` pero este solo permite ejecutar el primer hilo pero no el segundo, también colocar al final de `recorreNumero` un `return NULL` para finalizar totalmente el procedimiento pero tampoco funciona la violación del segmento sigue estando presente.

estoy trabajando en Ubuntu por terminal con c99

¿podrían ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba pasando como argumento un tipo de dato de tipo `struct`

```
typedef struct
{
   FILE *f;
   char *nomT;
   int numT;
} Data;
```

Luego, crea el hilo así:

```
Data data;
data.f = entrada;
data.nomT = nombre;
data.numT = numero;
pthread_t t1;

pthread_create (&t1, NULL, recorreNumero, &data);
```

Modifica el prototipo  de la funcion 'recorreNumero' así:

```
void *recorreNumero (Data *data);
```

En el cuerpo, des-referencia la estructura y trabaja con los datos.

Comment: Lo que no termino de ver es cómo esto va a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta...

Comment: hice algo similar a lo que logre entender de esta parte ahora funciona pero hasta un máximo de 5 hilos simultáneos hay alguna manera de subir este numero o doblarlo? no se si me doy a entender

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es peligroso por varios motivos:

**fichero de entrada**

Usas el mismo *stream* para las operaciones de lectura. Es decir, si en un hilo haces una lectura el cursor interno del *stream* se desplazará... **en todos los hilos**. Las operaciones sobre `entrada` deberían ser consideradas regiones críticas y no es así. Esto puede provocar la aparición de *lecturas sucias* (si se activan flags de error o `EOF`) o saltos (números que no se leen en algún hilo.

Para solucionar este problema tienes dos opciones:

1. Si necesitas que cada hilo procese el fichero completamente, deja que cada hilo abra el fichero en modo lectura (los modos de lectura no deberían ser bloqueantes entre sí). Con esta acción consigues que cada hilo maneje su propio *stream*, evitando así los problemas antes mencionados.
2. Si los hilos deben competir por los datos del fichero, implementa regiones críticas. Puedes hacer esto muy facilmente usando `pthread_mutex`. En este caso deberías evitar el uso de `rewind`.

**Escrituras sucias**

La salida a consola tampoco está protegida en una región crítica. Esto puede provocar que las salidas de los hilos se pisen entre ellas. Si dos hilos intentasen imprimir `"Hola\n"` un posible resultado podría ser:

```
HoHlola
a
```

Este problema únicamente se puede solucionar definiendo regiones críticas, que no es otra cosa que partes del código que solo podrán ser ejecutadas por un hilo cada vez. Un ejemplo:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *recorreNumero (FILE *entrada, char nomT[], int numT){
  int t = 0, numero = 0 ,primo = -1;
  char linea[13];
  FILE *salida;
  rewind(entrada);
  fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),entrada);
  salida = fopen (nomT,"w"); 
  while (fscanf(entrada, "%i", &numero) != EOF){
    t++;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);   // Inicio region critica
    printf("%i\n",numero );
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // Fin region critica
  }
  int lineasT = t/numT;
  int cont=1;
  rewind(entrada);
  fgets(linea,sizeof(linea),entrada);    
  while (fscanf(entrada, "%i", &numero) != EOF){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Extraido: %i \n", numero);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    primo = numprimo(numero);
    fprintf(salida, "%i  %i\n",numero,primo);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("%i\n",primo);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    cont++;
    if (cont == lineasT)
        break;
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  printf("Numero de filas: %d %i %s \n",t,primo,nomT);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  fclose(salida);
}
```

La estructura `lock` debe ser global porque tiene que estar compartida por todos los hilos... si la mueves dentro de la función entonces cada hilo definirá su propia región crítica y el problema se reproducirá nuevamente.

En cualquier caso no estaría de más simplificar la inicialización de los hilos haciendo caso a lo comentado por [@EddieRuiz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114658/463)

> trate de implementar un `thread_exit(NULL)` al final de `recorreNumero` pero este solo permite ejecutar el primer hilo pero no el segundo

Esa instrucción, mata el proceso actual, pero llegados a este punto ya le ha dejado el *stream* de entrada fastidiado al segundo hilo. Esta función está pensada para usarse en situaciones complejas en las que salir de la función `recorreNumero` no es tan sencillo como poner un `return`.

Piensa también que esta función hay que usarla con cuidado, ya que se pueden quedar recursos abiertos (ficheros, sockets, ...).

> también colocar al final de `recorreNumero` un `return NULL` para finalizar totalmente el procedimiento pero tampoco funciona la violación del segmento sigue estando presente.

Dado que la función tiene como tipo de salida `void*` deberías poner un `return` **SIEMPRE**.

El `return` no va a marcar que el hilo deje de dar problemas, sino que es una buena práctica que puede evitarte sorpresas desagradables. Piensa que la función va a retornar algo sí o sí... y si no le dices tu qué debe devolver va a coger un valor de algún sitio... y lo mismo no te gusta su elección.

Comment: lei el comentario hace poco, e implenté unos cambios en el codigo, por ejemplo ahora en vez de mandar el fichero entrada a traves de cada llamado de los hilos lo abro en el procedimiento __recorreNumero__ pensando que de este modo podria solucionar el problema haciendo que cada hilo lo abriera por separado pero esto no arreglo el problema, a pesar de abrirlo a modo de solo lectura